# System.AggregateException when creating DevOps workitems using ExecuteBatchRequest

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm getting an

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.
>   (Authentication failed because the connection could not be reused.)'

when trying to create multiple tasks linked to the same workItem using the Azure DevOps API.

I'm reworking an existing method which sent several `UpdateWorkItemAsync` calls to the `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient`, to instead use the `ExecuteBatchRequest` functionality to bundle them into one batch.

The previous method worked without any issues, but the batch-version has resulted in the exception from the start.

I've tried removing any additional fields to see which field was causing the issue, but that does not seem to affect the result at all.

I have the following method, which results in the exception when trying to perform the `ExecuteBatchRequest` method.

```
        public void CreateTasksOnWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, List<CreateTaskModel> tasksToCreate, bool suppressNotification = true)
        {
            if (!workItem.Id.HasValue)
            {
                return;
            }
            var batchRequests = new List<WitBatchRequest>();
            using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = _connection.Connect().GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>())
            {
                foreach (var taskModel in tasksToCreate)
                {
                    //Create Task - add more fields later
                    var taskDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();
                    AddOrUpdateFieldToJsonDocument(taskDocument, "System.Title", taskModel.Title, Operation.Add);
                    AddOrUpdateFieldToJsonDocument(taskDocument, "System.State", "To Do", Operation.Add);
                    if (taskModel.Tags != null && taskModel.Tags.Any())
                    {
                        AddTagsToWorkItem(taskDocument, workItem, taskModel.Tags);
                    }
                    if (taskModel.Assignee != null)
                    {
                        AssignWorkItem(taskDocument, taskModel.Assignee);
                    }
                    if (workItem.IsInIteration())
                    {
                        SetWorkItemIteration(taskDocument, workItem.GetIterationPath());
                    }
                    var valueToSet = new
                    {
                        url = workItem.Url,
                        rel = "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse"
                    };
                    AddRelationToDocument(taskDocument, valueToSet);
                    var taskBatch = witClient.CreateWorkItemBatchRequest(ProjectName, "Task", taskDocument, false, suppressNotification);
                    batchRequests.Add(taskBatch);
                }
                witClient.ExecuteBatchRequest(batchRequests).Wait();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please show the rest of the method?

Comment: That is all there is to it - I'm creating a witClient, setting up some batch requests and then trying to perform them. I tried to cut it down to the bare minimum I could to still get the error, but it seems the fields I decide to send along makes little difference. 
It fails whenever I'm trying to execute batch requests together.

I've updated the example to have the entire piece of code included

Comment: What is the message in the AggregateException? As far as I know, there is a restriction that the batch account and VMs should have the same location, or something like that.

Comment: Could you share your code in `_connection.Connect()'? The error said connection cannot be reused. Maybe the problem is how the connection is initialized.